# Find duplicate and check values range in table columns using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table in which I have two columns. `Min Range` and `Max Range`. I need to find duplicates in these two columns. And also values defined in these two columns form a range. This range should not be overlap by any row. Here is the pictorial representation

[image]

As `row 1` has `min range 70` and `max range 75`. So this `70` and `75` should not occur in other columns(Min Range and Max Range) of other rows. Also no other row can defined values in between 70 and 75 like `Min Range 71` and `Max Range 74`. Because it lies between `70` and `75`. I tried to write a logic but I stuck in the case shown in the picture. As `4th row(Test)` and `5th row(Test 2)` has valid ranges but how can I check that this is valid. `6th row(Test 3)` is invalid because its range is overlapping with the first row.

Here what I tried:

```
var contents = {};
    var errorMessageArray = []; 

    $table.find("tbody tr").each(function(index, element) {

        var $row = $(this);
        var rowId = $row.attr('id');

        var minRange = -1
        var maxRange = -1;

        var $secondColumn = $row.find('td:eq(1)');
        var $thirdColumn = $row.find('td:eq(2)');

        if(rowId.indexOf('inputRow') >= 0){
            minRange = parseInt($secondColumn.find('input').val());
            maxRange = parseInt($thirdColumn.find('input').val());
        } else {
            minRange = parseInt($secondColumn.html());
            maxRange = parseInt($thirdColumn.html());
        }

        var range = minRange + maxRange;

        var rowIndex = index + 1;

        if (minRange < 0) {
            var errorMessage = "In Row "+ rowIndex + " Min Range can not be less than 0";
            errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
        }

        if (maxRange > 100) {
            var errorMessage = "In Row "+ rowIndex + " Max Range can not be greater than 100";
            errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
        }

        if (minRange > maxRange) {
            var errorMessage = "In Row "+ rowIndex + " Min Range can not be greater than Max Range";
            errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
        }


        if (contents['minRange'] && contents['minRange']== minRange) {
            var errorMessage = "Min Range used in Row "+ rowIndex + " is already used.";
            errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
        } else {
            contents['minRange'] = minRange
        }

        if (contents['maxRange'] && contents['maxRange']== maxRange) {
            var errorMessage = "Max Range used in Row "+ rowIndex + " is already used.";
            errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
        } else {
            contents['maxRange'] = maxRange
        }

        if (contents['range'] && (contents['range']== range || range < contents['range']  )) {
            var errorMessage = "Range used in Row "+ rowIndex + " is overlapping.";
            errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
        } else {
            contents['range'] = range;
        }  
    });

    if (errorMessageArray.length > 0) {

    }
```

How can I solve it?

Here is the HTML:

```
<table class="tableDemo bordered" id="scoreScalesTable">
<thead>
    <tr style="display: table-row;">
        <th>Ranking Scale</th>
        <th>Min Range</th>
        <th>Max Range</th>
        <th>Icon</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="scoreScalesTable-3">
        <td class="Ranking Scale" id="scoreScalesTable-3-Ranking Scale">Cold</td>
        <td class="Min Range" id="scoreScalesTable-3-Min Range">70</td>
        <td class="Max Range" id="scoreScalesTable-3-Max Range">75</td>
        <td class="Icon" id="scoreScalesTable-3-Icon"><img alt="BlueStar.png" src="/images/BlueStar.png"></td>
        <td><a class="scoreScalesTable-ajaxEdit" id="scoreScalesTable-3-Edit" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Edit" src="/common/scripts/dynamicTable/images/edit.png"></a><a class="scoreScalesTable-deleteRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Delete Row" src="/common/scripts/dynamicTable/images/remove.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="scoreScalesTable-2">
        <td class="Ranking Scale" id="scoreScalesTable-2-Ranking Scale">Warm</td>
        <td class="Min Range" id="scoreScalesTable-2-Min Range">76</td>
        <td class="Max Range" id="scoreScalesTable-2-Max Range">90</td>
        <td class="Icon" id="scoreScalesTable-2-Icon"><img alt="BlueStar.png" src="/images/BlueStar.png"></td><td><a class="scoreScalesTable-ajaxEdit" id="scoreScalesTable-2-Edit" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Edit" src="/common/scripts/dynamicTable/images/edit.png"></a><a class="scoreScalesTable-deleteRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Delete Row" src="/common/scripts/dynamicTable/images/remove.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="scoreScalesTable-1">
        <td class="Ranking Scale" id="scoreScalesTable-1-Ranking Scale">Hot</td>
        <td class="Min Range" id="scoreScalesTable-1-Min Range">91</td>
        <td class="Max Range" id="scoreScalesTable-1-Max Range">100</td>
        <td class="Icon" id="scoreScalesTable-1-Icon"><img alt="BlueStar.png" src="/images/BlueStar.png"></td>
        <td><a class="scoreScalesTable-ajaxEdit" id="scoreScalesTable-1-Edit" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Edit" src="/common/scripts/dynamicTable/images/edit.png"></a><a class="scoreScalesTable-deleteRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Delete Row" src="/common/scripts/dynamicTable/images/remove.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="inputform" id="scoreScalesTable-inputRow0" style="display: table-row;">
        <td class="ajaxReq"><input name="Ranking Scale" type="text" placeholder="Enter Ranking Scale" value=""></td>
        <td class="ajaxReq"><input name="Min Range" type="text" placeholder="Enter Minimum Range" value=""></td>
        <td class="ajaxReq"><input name="Max Range" type="text" placeholder="Enter Maximum Range" value=""></td>
        <td class="ajaxReq"><div class="ddOutOfVision" id="msdrpdd20_msddHolder" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;"><select name="Icon" tabindex="-1" id="msdrpdd20"><option value="/images/BlueStar.png" data-image="/images/BlueStar.png">BlueStar.png</option><option value="/images/BlackStar.png" data-image="/images/BlackStar.png">BlackStar.png</option><option value="/images/RedStar.png" data-image="/images/RedStar.png">RedStar.png</option><option value="/images/YellowStar.png" data-image="/images/YellowStar.png">YellowStar.png</option><option value="/images/BrownStar.png" data-image="/images/BrownStar.png">BrownStar.png</option><option value="/images/OrangeStar.png" data-image="/images/OrangeStar.png">OrangeStar.png</option><option value="/images/GreenStar.png" data-image="/images/GreenStar.png">GreenStar.png</option><option value="/images/PurpleStar.png" data-image="/images/PurpleStar.png">PurpleStar.png</option><option value="/images/WhiteStar.png" data-image="/images/WhiteStar.png">WhiteStar.png</option><option value="/images/CyanStar.png" data-image="/images/CyanStar.png">CyanStar.png</option></select></div><div tabindex="0" class="dd ddcommon borderRadius" id="msdrpdd20_msdd" style="width: 170px;"><div class="ddTitle borderRadiusTp"><span class="divider"></span><span class="ddArrow arrowoff"></span><span class="ddTitleText " id="msdrpdd20_title"><img class="fnone" src="/images/BlackStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">BlackStar.png</span><span class="description" style="display: none;"></span></span></div><input class="text shadow borderRadius" id="msdrpdd20_titleText" style="display: none;" type="text" autocomplete="off"><div class="ddChild ddchild_ border shadow" id="msdrpdd20_child" style="top: 24px; height: 213px; display: none; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 1;"><ul><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/BlueStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">BlueStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_ selected"><img class="fnone" src="/images/BlackStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">BlackStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/RedStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">RedStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/YellowStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">YellowStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/BrownStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">BrownStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/OrangeStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">OrangeStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/GreenStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">GreenStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/PurpleStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">PurpleStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/WhiteStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">WhiteStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/CyanStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">CyanStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li></ul></div></div></td>
        <td><a class="scoreScalesTable-addRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Add Row" src="/common/scripts/dynamicTable/images/addRow.png"></a><a class="scoreScalesTable-deleteRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Delete Row" src="/common/scripts/dynamicTable/images/remove.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="inputform" id="scoreScalesTable-inputRow1">
        <td class="ajaxReq"><input name="Ranking Scale" type="text" placeholder="Enter Ranking Scale" value=""></td>
        <td class="ajaxReq"><input name="Min Range" type="text" placeholder="Enter Minimum Range" value=""></td>
        <td class="ajaxReq"><input name="Max Range" type="text" placeholder="Enter Maximum Range" value=""></td>
        <td class="ajaxReq"><div class="ddOutOfVision" id="msdrpdd22_msddHolder" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;"><select name="Icon" tabindex="-1" id="msdrpdd22"><option value="/images/BlueStar.png" data-image="/images/BlueStar.png">BlueStar.png</option><option value="/images/BlackStar.png" data-image="/images/BlackStar.png">BlackStar.png</option><option value="/images/RedStar.png" data-image="/images/RedStar.png">RedStar.png</option><option value="/images/YellowStar.png" data-image="/images/YellowStar.png">YellowStar.png</option><option value="/images/BrownStar.png" data-image="/images/BrownStar.png">BrownStar.png</option><option value="/images/OrangeStar.png" data-image="/images/OrangeStar.png">OrangeStar.png</option><option value="/images/GreenStar.png" data-image="/images/GreenStar.png">GreenStar.png</option><option value="/images/PurpleStar.png" data-image="/images/PurpleStar.png">PurpleStar.png</option><option value="/images/WhiteStar.png" data-image="/images/WhiteStar.png">WhiteStar.png</option><option value="/images/CyanStar.png" data-image="/images/CyanStar.png">CyanStar.png</option></select></div><div tabindex="0" class="dd ddcommon borderRadius" id="msdrpdd22_msdd" style="width: 170px;"><div class="ddTitle borderRadiusTp"><span class="divider"></span><span class="ddArrow arrowoff"></span><span class="ddTitleText " id="msdrpdd22_title"><img class="fnone" src="/images/BrownStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">BrownStar.png</span><span class="description" style="display: none;"></span></span></div><input class="text shadow borderRadius" id="msdrpdd22_titleText" style="display: none;" type="text" autocomplete="off"><div class="ddChild ddchild_ border shadow" id="msdrpdd22_child" style="top: -213px; height: 213px; display: none; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 1;"><ul><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/BlueStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">BlueStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/BlackStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">BlackStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/RedStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">RedStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/YellowStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">YellowStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_ selected"><img class="fnone" src="/images/BrownStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">BrownStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/OrangeStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">OrangeStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/GreenStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">GreenStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/PurpleStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">PurpleStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/WhiteStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">WhiteStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/CyanStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">CyanStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li></ul></div></div></td>
        <td><a class="scoreScalesTable-addRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Add Row" src="/common/scripts/dynamicTable/images/addRow.png"></a><a class="scoreScalesTable-deleteRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Delete Row" src="/common/scripts/dynamicTable/images/remove.png"></a></td>
    </tr><
    tr class="inputform" id="scoreScalesTable-inputRow2">
        <td class="ajaxReq"><input name="Ranking Scale" type="text" placeholder="Enter Ranking Scale" value=""></td>
        <td class="ajaxReq"><input name="Min Range" type="text" placeholder="Enter Minimum Range" value=""></td>
        <td class="ajaxReq"><input name="Max Range" type="text" placeholder="Enter Maximum Range" value=""></td>
        <td class="ajaxReq"><div class="ddOutOfVision" id="msdrpdd23_msddHolder" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;"><select name="Icon" tabindex="-1" id="msdrpdd23"><option value="/images/BlueStar.png" data-image="/images/BlueStar.png">BlueStar.png</option><option value="/images/BlackStar.png" data-image="/images/BlackStar.png">BlackStar.png</option><option value="/images/RedStar.png" data-image="/images/RedStar.png">RedStar.png</option><option value="/images/YellowStar.png" data-image="/images/YellowStar.png">YellowStar.png</option><option value="/images/BrownStar.png" data-image="/images/BrownStar.png">BrownStar.png</option><option value="/images/OrangeStar.png" data-image="/images/OrangeStar.png">OrangeStar.png</option><option value="/images/GreenStar.png" data-image="/images/GreenStar.png">GreenStar.png</option><option value="/images/PurpleStar.png" data-image="/images/PurpleStar.png">PurpleStar.png</option><option value="/images/WhiteStar.png" data-image="/images/WhiteStar.png">WhiteStar.png</option><option value="/images/CyanStar.png" data-image="/images/CyanStar.png">CyanStar.png</option></select></div><div tabindex="0" class="dd ddcommon borderRadius" id="msdrpdd23_msdd" style="width: 170px;"><div class="ddTitle borderRadiusTp"><span class="divider"></span><span class="ddArrow arrowoff"></span><span class="ddTitleText " id="msdrpdd23_title"><img class="fnone" src="/images/YellowStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">YellowStar.png</span><span class="description" style="display: none;"></span></span></div><input class="text shadow borderRadius" id="msdrpdd23_titleText" style="display: none;" type="text" autocomplete="off"><div class="ddChild ddchild_ border shadow" id="msdrpdd23_child" style="top: -213px; height: 213px; display: none; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 1;"><ul><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/BlueStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">BlueStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/BlackStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">BlackStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/RedStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">RedStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_ selected"><img class="fnone" src="/images/YellowStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">YellowStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/BrownStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">BrownStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/OrangeStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">OrangeStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/GreenStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">GreenStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/PurpleStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">PurpleStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/WhiteStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">WhiteStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li><li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src="/images/CyanStar.png"><span class="ddlabel">CyanStar.png</span><div class="clear"></div></li></ul></div></div></td>
        <td><a class="scoreScalesTable-addRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Add Row" src="/common/scripts/dynamicTable/images/addRow.png"></a><a class="scoreScalesTable-deleteRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Delete Row" src="/common/scripts/dynamicTable/images/remove.png"></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Your `.each()` loop cycles through all rows one by one. You just can't compare the values you have in a row against the values of all other rows in that same loop. At least a second loop is needed. Could you provide the rendered HTML, so I could help you more?

Comment: Thanks. Check my Edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fully commented the code, «[Rubber Duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/)» style.
Some questions are answered below.

Feel free to ask!

Here is the code... The CodePen link is under it.
The SO snippet was removed (but should still be accessible in the edit history) because of the post character limit of 30 000 characters! *.oO(lol!)*

```
console.clear();

var $table = $("#scoreScalesTable");

function check(){
  console.clear();

  // Remove all highlights
  $table.find("tbody tr").removeClass("highlight");

  var rangeArray = [];
  var errorMessageArray = []; 

  // FIRST LOOP to get the data to work on... And catch the first errors.
  $table.find("tbody tr").each(function(index, element) {

    var $row = $(this);
    var rowId = $row.attr('id');

    //console.log($row.find("td").first().html());

    var minRange = -1
    var maxRange = -1;

    var $secondColumn = $row.find('td:eq(1)');
    var $thirdColumn = $row.find('td:eq(2)');

    if(rowId.indexOf('inputRow') >= 0){
      var secondVal = $secondColumn.find('input').val();
      var thirdVal = $thirdColumn.find('input').val();

      // If there's values.
      if(secondVal != "" && thirdVal!= ""){
        minRange = parseInt(secondVal);
        maxRange = parseInt(thirdVal);
      }
    } else {
      minRange = parseInt($secondColumn.html());
      maxRange = parseInt($thirdColumn.html());
    }

    var range = maxRange - minRange;  //   Strangely was WAS minRange + maxRange    (???) Doesn't seem to be used.

    var rowIndex = index + 1;

    // If there's values.
    if(secondVal != "" && thirdVal!= ""){

      var errorMessage = "";  // Declare it here

      if (minRange < 0) {
        errorMessage = "In Row "+ rowIndex + " Min Range can not be less than 0";
        errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
        $table.find("tbody tr").eq(index).addClass("range_highlight");
      }

      if (maxRange > 100) {
        errorMessage = "In Row "+ rowIndex + " Max Range can not be greater than 100";
        errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
        $table.find("tbody tr").eq(index).addClass("range_highlight");
      }

      if (minRange > maxRange) {
        errorMessage = "In Row "+ rowIndex + " Min Range can not be greater than Max Range";
        errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
        $table.find("tbody tr").eq(index).addClass("range_highlight");
      }

      // If no error
      if(errorMessage==""){
        var content = {
          minRange: minRange,
          maxRange: maxRange,
          range: range
        };
        rangeArray.push(content);
      }
    }
  }); // Stop that loop here.


  console.log("Row taken in account:\n"+rangeArray.length);

  // Second looping now to check overlappings, but withing the rangeArray
  var errorIndexes_on = [];
  var errorIndexes_because = [];
  var errorTriggedOn = [];

  for(i=0;i<rangeArray.length;i++){

    var errorMessage;

    //console.log("checking row #"+(i+1));

    // Check this range angainst all other ranges
    for(k=0;k<rangeArray.length;k++){

      // Don't compare against self, skip that iteration.
      if(k!=i){

        // Always use the right indexes depending on when the trigger occured.
        var eq;
        (k>=i) ? eq = k : eq = i; // To keep the conflicting line, assuming the last is always in fault compared to previouses.
        (k>=i) ? rowIndex = k + 1 : rowIndex = i + 1;   // For error messages, same reason as above.
        (k>=i) ? overlaped = i + 1 : overlaped = k + 1;

        // if overlap based on min
        if(rangeArray[i].minRange >= rangeArray[k].minRange && rangeArray[i].minRange <= rangeArray[k].maxRange){  // min i inside k

          // hightlight the row and log the error
          errorTriggedOn.push("min");

          $table.find("tbody tr").eq(eq).addClass("range_highlight");

          errorMessage = "Range in Row "+ rowIndex + " overlaps the range in row " + overlaped;
          errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);

          errorIndexes_on.push(rowIndex);
          errorIndexes_because.push(overlaped);
        }

        // if overlap based on max
        else if(rangeArray[i].maxRange >= rangeArray[k].minRange && rangeArray[i].maxRange <= rangeArray[k].maxRange){  // man i inside k

          // hightlight the row and log the error
          errorTriggedOn.push("max");

          $table.find("tbody tr").eq(eq).addClass("range_highlight");

          errorMessage = "Range in Row "+ rowIndex + " overlaps the range in row " + overlaped;
          errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);

          errorIndexes_on.push(rowIndex);
          errorIndexes_because.push(overlaped);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Console debuging results.
  console.log( "rangeArray:\n" + JSON.stringify(rangeArray));
  console.log( "errorMessageArray:\n" + JSON.stringify(errorMessageArray));

  console.log( "errorIndexes_on:\n" + JSON.stringify(errorIndexes_on));
  console.log( "errorIndexes_because:\n" + JSON.stringify(errorIndexes_because));
  console.log( "errorTriggedOn:\n" + JSON.stringify(errorTriggedOn));

  // Filter error message
  errorMessageArray.sort();
  for(i=0;i<errorMessageArray.length;i++){
    if(errorMessageArray[i] == errorMessageArray[i-1]){
      errorMessageArray.splice(i,1);
    }
  }

  // Console debuging results after error messages filtering.
  console.log("==================================================");
  console.log( "FILTERED errorMessageArray:\n" + JSON.stringify(errorMessageArray));

  //if (errorMessageArray.length > 0) {   // Condition commented out... But can be used for additional action.
    var errAmount = errorMessageArray.length;
    var accord = " ERROR";
    if (errorMessageArray.length > 1) {
      accord = " ERRORS";
    }
    console.log(errAmount+ accord);
  //}

} // check()

// Run check on load, if you wish.
// check();

// Check button click handler
$("#test").on("click", check);

// Ensure only digits in range inputs... Esle highlight the row.
$("[name*='Range']").on("input paste", function(){

  // Remove all character highlights.
  $("tr").removeClass("character_highlight");

  var BADmatches = $(this).val().match(/\D/g)
  //console.log( BADmatches.length );
  if( BADmatches != null ){
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("character_highlight");
  }
});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/LjoBzm?editors=0011)

---

Answers to questions:

1. `if(k!=i){..}`

That is a condition to prevent a row being compared with itself.
So, having row #1 index in `i`, we DON'T want to perform an overlap comparison with row #1 index in `k`... Since it would ALWAYS find an overlap!

2. The two conditions

Those two are to detect if the start point of the `i` range is within the `k` range **OR** if the end point of the `i` range is within the `k` range. If at least one is true, there an overlap for sure.

No need to check if both are true, we know there's an overlap.

If none are true, we consider no overlap for now.
But say line #1 range is 10-90 in `i` and line #3 range is 50-60 in `k`.

No overlap detected on that iteration.
This obvious overlap will be caugth when the loop will test line #3 in `i` compared to line #1 in `k`. So just later in the looping. ;)

We have to "wait" for that next iteration for two reasons: 1) not trigger the error twice and 2) know which line is the previous line.

Lines are "considered correct" until the loop finds **a previous line** ovelapping. That is why there is the `eq` variable, setted by `(k>=i) ? eq = k : eq = i;`, to be sure that we don't highlight a previous line, but a following one.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. Thanks for your help :) . First loop is very clear, just check some validations and create objects. Then for range validation start another loop.  Just trying to understand the variables in `if(k!=i){..}` and the two if conditions `if(rangeArray[i].minRange >= rangeArray[k].minRange && rangeArray[i].minRange <= rangeArray[k].maxRange)` and `else if(rangeArray[i].maxRange >= rangeArray[k].minRange && rangeArray[i].maxRange <= rangeArray[k].maxRange)`. I mean how they are working. But again thnk you so much for your help. :)

Answer (score -1):

To check if two ranges overlap, you merely have to see if either range contains any of the other's endpoints. I do this by seeing if an endpoint is more than the other's `minRange` and less than the other's `maxRange`.

I chose to loop through every `$("tbody tr")` and cache each row's `minRange` and `maxRange`. Then, still inside the `.each()`, I check the current row against all the previous rows with a `forEach` (this could be replaced with a `for` loop if you're extremely worried about browser compatibility):

```
rows.forEach(function(r) {
  // First make sure all the endpoints are defined
  if (minRange && r.minRange && maxRange && r.maxRange) {

    // Check endpoints
    if ((minRange > r.minRange && minRange < r.maxRange) ||
      (maxRange > r.minRange && maxRange < r.maxRange) ||
      (r.minRange > minRange && r.minRange < maxRange) ||
      (r.minRange > minRange && r.minRange < maxRange)) {
      errorMessage = "Range used in Row " + rowIndex + " is overlapping.";
      errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
    }

  }
});
```

Note that I have to check both ways: see if the current row has an endpoint inside each previous row *and* see if the given other row has an endpoint inside the current one.

To be efficient, I also thought it wise to check for matching endpoints in the same `forEach`.

Here is my finished code. I removed image `src`s so the 404 errors wouldn't show up in the console. Click the validate button to run the checks.

```js
function validate() {
  var errorMessageArray = [];

  var rows = [];
  
  var $table = $('table');

  $table.find("tbody tr").each(function(index) {

    var $row = $(this);
    var rowId = $row.attr('id');

    var $secondColumn = $row.find('td:eq(1)');
    var $thirdColumn = $row.find('td:eq(2)');

    var minRange;
    var maxRange;

    if (rowId.indexOf('inputRow') >= 0) {
      minRange = parseInt($secondColumn.find('input').val());
      maxRange = parseInt($thirdColumn.find('input').val());
    } else {
      minRange = parseInt($secondColumn.html());
      maxRange = parseInt($thirdColumn.html());
    }

    var errorMessage;

    var rowIndex = index + 1;

    if (minRange < 0) {
      errorMessage = "In Row " + rowIndex + " Min Range can not be less than 0";
      errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
    }

    if (minRange > maxRange) {
      errorMessage = "In Row " + rowIndex + " Min Range can not be greater than Max Range";
      errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
    }

    if (maxRange > 100) {
      errorMessage = "In Row " + rowIndex + " Max Range can not be greater than 100";
      errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
    }

    rows.forEach(function(r) {
      if (minRange && r.minRange && minRange === r.minRange) {
        errorMessage = "Min Range used in Row " + rowIndex + " is already used.";
        errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
      }

      if (maxRange && r.maxRange && maxRange === r.maxRange) {
        errorMessage = "Max Range used in Row " + rowIndex + " is already used.";
        errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
      }

      if (minRange && r.minRange && maxRange && r.maxRange) {
        if ((minRange > r.minRange && minRange < r.maxRange) ||
          (maxRange > r.minRange && maxRange < r.maxRange) ||
          (r.minRange > minRange && r.minRange < maxRange) ||
          (r.minRange > minRange && r.minRange < maxRange)) {
          errorMessage = "Range used in Row " + rowIndex + " is overlapping.";
          errorMessageArray.push(errorMessage);
        }
      }
    });

    rows.push({
      id: rowId,
      minRange: minRange,
      maxRange: maxRange,
      range: maxRange - minRange
    });
  });

  if (errorMessageArray.length > 0) {
   errorMessageArray.forEach(function (e) {
     console.error(e);
    });
  }
  
  return rows;
}

$('button').click(validate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableDemo bordered" id="scoreScalesTable">
  <thead>
    <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <th>Ranking Scale</th>
      <th>Min Range</th>
      <th>Max Range</th>
      <th>Icon</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="scoreScalesTable-3">
      <td class="Ranking Scale" id="scoreScalesTable-3-Ranking Scale">Cold</td>
      <td class="Min Range" id="scoreScalesTable-3-Min Range">70</td>
      <td class="Max Range" id="scoreScalesTable-3-Max Range">75</td>
      <td class="Icon" id="scoreScalesTable-3-Icon"><img alt="BlueStar.png" src=""></td>
      <td>
        <a class="scoreScalesTable-ajaxEdit" id="scoreScalesTable-3-Edit" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Edit" src=""></a>
        <a class="scoreScalesTable-deleteRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Delete Row" src=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="scoreScalesTable-2">
      <td class="Ranking Scale" id="scoreScalesTable-2-Ranking Scale">Warm</td>
      <td class="Min Range" id="scoreScalesTable-2-Min Range">76</td>
      <td class="Max Range" id="scoreScalesTable-2-Max Range">90</td>
      <td class="Icon" id="scoreScalesTable-2-Icon"><img alt="BlueStar.png" src=""></td>
      <td>
        <a class="scoreScalesTable-ajaxEdit" id="scoreScalesTable-2-Edit" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Edit" src=""></a>
        <a class="scoreScalesTable-deleteRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Delete Row" src=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="scoreScalesTable-1">
      <td class="Ranking Scale" id="scoreScalesTable-1-Ranking Scale">Hot</td>
      <td class="Min Range" id="scoreScalesTable-1-Min Range">91</td>
      <td class="Max Range" id="scoreScalesTable-1-Max Range">100</td>
      <td class="Icon" id="scoreScalesTable-1-Icon"><img alt="BlueStar.png" src=""></td>
      <td>
        <a class="scoreScalesTable-ajaxEdit" id="scoreScalesTable-1-Edit" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Edit" src=""></a>
        <a class="scoreScalesTable-deleteRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Delete Row" src="g"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="inputform" id="scoreScalesTable-inputRow0" style="display: table-row;">
      <td class="ajaxReq">
        <input name="Ranking Scale" type="text" placeholder="Enter Ranking Scale" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="ajaxReq">
        <input name="Min Range" type="text" placeholder="Enter Minimum Range" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="ajaxReq">
        <input name="Max Range" type="text" placeholder="Enter Maximum Range" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="ajaxReq">
        <div class="ddOutOfVision" id="msdrpdd20_msddHolder" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
          <select name="Icon" tabindex="-1" id="msdrpdd20">
            <option value="/images/BlueStar.png" data-image="/images/BlueStar.png">BlueStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/BlackStar.png" data-image="/images/BlackStar.png">BlackStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/RedStar.png" data-image="/images/RedStar.png">RedStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/YellowStar.png" data-image="/images/YellowStar.png">YellowStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/BrownStar.png" data-image="/images/BrownStar.png">BrownStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/OrangeStar.png" data-image="/images/OrangeStar.png">OrangeStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/GreenStar.png" data-image="/images/GreenStar.png">GreenStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/PurpleStar.png" data-image="/images/PurpleStar.png">PurpleStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/WhiteStar.png" data-image="/images/WhiteStar.png">WhiteStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/CyanStar.png" data-image="/images/CyanStar.png">CyanStar.png</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div tabindex="0" class="dd ddcommon borderRadius" id="msdrpdd20_msdd" style="width: 170px;">
          <div class="ddTitle borderRadiusTp"><span class="divider"></span><span class="ddArrow arrowoff"></span><span class="ddTitleText " id="msdrpdd20_title"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">BlackStar.png</span><span class="description" style="display: none;"></span></span>
          </div>
          <input class="text shadow borderRadius" id="msdrpdd20_titleText" style="display: none;" type="text" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="ddChild ddchild_ border shadow" id="msdrpdd20_child" style="top: 24px; height: 213px; display: none; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 1;">
            <ul>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">BlueStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_ selected"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">BlackStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">RedStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">YellowStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">BrownStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">OrangeStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">GreenStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">PurpleStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">WhiteStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">CyanStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="scoreScalesTable-addRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Add Row" src=""></a>
        <a class="scoreScalesTable-deleteRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Delete Row" src=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="inputform" id="scoreScalesTable-inputRow1">
      <td class="ajaxReq">
        <input name="Ranking Scale" type="text" placeholder="Enter Ranking Scale" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="ajaxReq">
        <input name="Min Range" type="text" placeholder="Enter Minimum Range" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="ajaxReq">
        <input name="Max Range" type="text" placeholder="Enter Maximum Range" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="ajaxReq">
        <div class="ddOutOfVision" id="msdrpdd22_msddHolder" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
          <select name="Icon" tabindex="-1" id="msdrpdd22">
            <option value="/images/BlueStar.png" data-image="/images/BlueStar.png">BlueStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/BlackStar.png" data-image="/images/BlackStar.png">BlackStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/RedStar.png" data-image="/images/RedStar.png">RedStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/YellowStar.png" data-image="/images/YellowStar.png">YellowStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/BrownStar.png" data-image="/images/BrownStar.png">BrownStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/OrangeStar.png" data-image="/images/OrangeStar.png">OrangeStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/GreenStar.png" data-image="/images/GreenStar.png">GreenStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/PurpleStar.png" data-image="/images/PurpleStar.png">PurpleStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/WhiteStar.png" data-image="/images/WhiteStar.png">WhiteStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/CyanStar.png" data-image="/images/CyanStar.png">CyanStar.png</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div tabindex="0" class="dd ddcommon borderRadius" id="msdrpdd22_msdd" style="width: 170px;">
          <div class="ddTitle borderRadiusTp"><span class="divider"></span><span class="ddArrow arrowoff"></span><span class="ddTitleText " id="msdrpdd22_title"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">BrownStar.png</span><span class="description" style="display: none;"></span></span>
          </div>
          <input class="text shadow borderRadius" id="msdrpdd22_titleText" style="display: none;" type="text" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="ddChild ddchild_ border shadow" id="msdrpdd22_child" style="top: -213px; height: 213px; display: none; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 1;">
            <ul>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">BlueStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">BlackStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">RedStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">YellowStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_ selected"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">BrownStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">OrangeStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">GreenStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">PurpleStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">WhiteStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">CyanStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="scoreScalesTable-addRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Add Row" src=""></a>
        <a class="scoreScalesTable-deleteRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Delete Row" src=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="inputform" id="scoreScalesTable-inputRow2">
      <td class="ajaxReq">
        <input name="Ranking Scale" type="text" placeholder="Enter Ranking Scale" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="ajaxReq">
        <input name="Min Range" type="text" placeholder="Enter Minimum Range" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="ajaxReq">
        <input name="Max Range" type="text" placeholder="Enter Maximum Range" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="ajaxReq">
        <div class="ddOutOfVision" id="msdrpdd23_msddHolder" style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
          <select name="Icon" tabindex="-1" id="msdrpdd23">
            <option value="/images/BlueStar.png" data-image="/images/BlueStar.png">BlueStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/BlackStar.png" data-image="/images/BlackStar.png">BlackStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/RedStar.png" data-image="/images/RedStar.png">RedStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/YellowStar.png" data-image="/images/YellowStar.png">YellowStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/BrownStar.png" data-image="/images/BrownStar.png">BrownStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/OrangeStar.png" data-image="/images/OrangeStar.png">OrangeStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/GreenStar.png" data-image="/images/GreenStar.png">GreenStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/PurpleStar.png" data-image="/images/PurpleStar.png">PurpleStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/WhiteStar.png" data-image="/images/WhiteStar.png">WhiteStar.png</option>
            <option value="/images/CyanStar.png" data-image="/images/CyanStar.png">CyanStar.png</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div tabindex="0" class="dd ddcommon borderRadius" id="msdrpdd23_msdd" style="width: 170px;">
          <div class="ddTitle borderRadiusTp"><span class="divider"></span><span class="ddArrow arrowoff"></span><span class="ddTitleText " id="msdrpdd23_title"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">YellowStar.png</span><span class="description" style="display: none;"></span></span>
          </div>
          <input class="text shadow borderRadius" id="msdrpdd23_titleText" style="display: none;" type="text" autocomplete="off">
          <div class="ddChild ddchild_ border shadow" id="msdrpdd23_child" style="top: -213px; height: 213px; display: none; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 1;">
            <ul>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">BlueStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">BlackStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">RedStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_ selected"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">YellowStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">BrownStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">OrangeStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">GreenStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">PurpleStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">WhiteStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="enabled _msddli_"><img class="fnone" src=""><span class="ddlabel">CyanStar.png</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="scoreScalesTable-addRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Add Row" src=""></a>
        <a class="scoreScalesTable-deleteRow" href="javascript:;"><img alt="Delete Row" src=""></a>
      </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>

  <button>Validate</button>
```

[Here it is on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7nwL3v0/1/).